# Iterating and Deleting from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an object and I want to remove the element from it.

Eg : My object is like as below

```
var DecisionObj = '{"Decision":[{"recid":"1183","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"662","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"752","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""}]}';
```

Suppose I want to delete row with recid = 662

Below is the code i tried

```
var DecisionObj = '{"Decision":[{"recid":"1183","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"662","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"752","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""}]}';
obj = JSON.parse(DecisionObj);
console.log("BEFORE==="+JSON.stringify(obj));
var ddcnt = obj.Decision.length;
var recval = 662;
for (e = 0; e < ddcnt; e++) 
{
     //var DRecVal = obj.Decision[e].recid;
     var DRecVal = obj.Decision[e].recid;
     if(recval == DRecVal)
     { 
       obj.Decision.splice(e,1);
     }
}
console.log("AFTER==="+JSON.stringify(obj));
```

But the above code gives me an error like TypeError: 
obj.Decision[e] is undefined on line 21.

How shall I solve this.Help appreciated!Thanks!

Comment: Use instead `for(properties in obj.Decision)` and access `DRecVal` by `properties.recid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a

```
break;
```

after the splice() call in the loop.

Comment: Rhinodevil , You are a genius man!You solved my query in such a short line of code.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

'.length' is not zero indexed. Ammend your variable to the following:

```
var ddcnt = obj.Decision.length - 1;
```

Comment: you get undefined, because the loop is looking for a 4th item at index 3 in the array.

Comment: yes, becuase `.length` returns a one-indexed value and arrays are zero-indexed

Comment: `length` isn't indexed, as such; it's an absolute value (whether the array starts at 0 or 1, it still has N items).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var DecisionObj = '{"Decision":[{"recid":"1183","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"662","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"752","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""}]}';
obj = JSON.parse(DecisionObj);
console.log("BEFORE==="+JSON.stringify(obj));
var ddcnt = obj.Decision.length;
var recval = 662;
for (e = 0; e < ddcnt; e++) 
{
     //var DRecVal = obj.Decision[e].recid;
     var DRecVal = obj.Decision[e].recid;
     if(recval == DRecVal)
     { 
       obj.Decision.splice(e,1);
       break;
     }
}
console.log("AFTER==="+JSON.stringify(obj));
```

UPDATE :

```
    function removeID(recid){       
        var DecisionObj = '{"Decision":[{"recid":"1183","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"662","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"752","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""}]}';
        obj = JSON.parse(DecisionObj);
        console.log("BEFORE==="+JSON.stringify(obj));
        var ddcnt = obj.Decision.length;
        for (e = 0; e < ddcnt; e++) {
            var DRecVal = obj.Decision[e].recid;
            if(recid == DRecVal){ 
                obj.Decision.splice(e,1);
            }
        }
        console.log("AFTER==="+JSON.stringify(obj));
    }


removeID(752);
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar.I tried this code but then I am not able to remove the last element here.Here the last element is 752.Any suggestion?

Comment: @MuktaChourishi Are you not trying to remove the last element? Your question says that you need to remove a row with recid 662. The above code removes row with recid 662 as stated in your question.

Comment: That's an example.I would get recid dynamically and it may happen that 752 is to be deleted.

Comment: @MuktaChourishi then you can put this into a function and pass the recid to be deleted as a parameter. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Divakar , Code is not working for the last element in array for others it does.

Comment: @MuktaChourishi I have updated my answer. Use the removeID function. It should work now.

Comment: In that case Divakar I am only able to remove last element and not others.

Comment: @MuktaChourishi Updated my answer. It will work now.

Answer (score 0):

This works accepting the recid string:

```js
var DecisionObj = '{"Decision":[{"recid":"1183","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"662","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"752","reason":"Approved but with different Funding Amount","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""}]}';

var DecisionObj = JSON.parse(DecisionObj);


function removeByRecid(arr, recid) {
  for (var elem in arr) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(elem)) {
      if((typeof arr[elem].recid !== 'undefined') && (arr[elem].recid == recid))
      {
        console.log(arr[elem]);
        var index = arr.indexOf(elem);
        arr.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}


function removeRecid(obj, recid) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === '[object Array]') {
        removeByRecid(obj[key], recid);
      }
    }
  }
}


console.log(DecisionObj);
removeRecid(DecisionObj, "1183");
console.log(DecisionObj);
```